# I need to use the first array values to calculate sizes in second array, if duplicate values appear in data, I would like a sum of values in size?

Tags: java, arrays, indexing

I have two arrays one is,

```
data[10] = {10,10,30,30,90,60,71,91,90,91};
```

and the other is

```
size[10] = {1000,20000,30000,40000,50000,60000,7100,8000,9000,9100};
```

What I want to do, is to be able to index through the data array above, and pick out the sizes from the size array. However for duplicate values in the data array I want the sizes to be aggregated for example, the Size for value 10 should be 21000. I've tried using a `boolean duplicates;` and the various different loops in order to figure out my problem, but so far I am having little success.

Comment: Could you maybe elaborate a bit further? So is the relation `data[i]` -> `size[i]` or `data[i]` -> `size[data[i]]`? So like how do you get from 10 to 21000?

Comment: data[i] -> size[i]

Comment: Okay. Got it now. Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: Parrallel Arrays are a sign of poor design. This is Java not QBasic! https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2014/06/03/anti-pattern-parallel-collections/

Answer (score 3):

You can simply use a `Map` and fill it with keys from your `data` array and values from your `size` array. Something like this:

```
int[] data = { 10, 10, 30, 30, 90, 60, 71, 91, 90, 91 };
int[] size = { 1000, 20000, 30000, 40000, 50000, 60000, 7100, 8000, 9000, 9100 };

Map<Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();

for (int i = 0; i < data.length; ++i)
{
    map.put(data[i], map.getOrDefault(data[i], 0) + size[i]);
}

System.out.println(map);
```

This prints

```
{71=7100, 10=21000, 90=59000, 91=17100, 60=60000, 30=70000}
```

Answer (score 0):

try below

```
    Map<Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();

for(int i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
    if(map.get(data[i]) == null) {
        map.put(data[i], size[i]);
    } else {
        int value = map.get(data[i]);
        value = value + size[i];
        map.put(data[i], value);
    }
}
```

finally map contains the values that you want.